# what is the equivalent of the "literal" tag in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am migrating a website from asp.net to asp.net mvc

in the asp.net site there are many places where they have "literal" tags and the server generates a bunch of html and sticks in in the literal tag.

what is the equivalent of doign this in asp.net mvc.  Should i shove this in ViewData?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent is to not make the same bad design choices the original developer made.

But, since we live in the real world, you'd shove their strings-which-contain-html into the presentation model for a particular page and then write it to the response stream.

In your Model:

```
public class MyPageModel
{
  public string HolyCrapItsHtml {get;set;}
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyPage()
{
  return View(new MyPageModel
         {HolyCrapItsHtml = OldCode.GetHtmlICantBelieveIt()});
}
```

And in your page:

```
<div>
  In the olden days, we'd concatenate our webpages together from strings like:
  <%= Model.HolyCrapItsHtml %>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this response.  can you offer an alternative approach that i can aim to refactor this to?

Comment: Essentially the same thing, except instead of concatenating your html together in (with this example) OldCode.GethtmlICantBelieveIt, in your controller you gather your data that makes up that html's content, place it within models, and render all your html within your view using your model's contents.  A few minutes researching MVC and you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Don't bother with a MyPageModel, just stick with ViewData but use equals instead of the colon.

```
<%= ViewData("SomeVarName") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Razor, you'd do the following if not using strongly-typed helpers

```
@Model.YourVarName
```

If you're working in with strongly-typed view model, you can use the ValueFor() helper

```
@Html.ValueFor(m => m.YourVarName)
```

If you just have a few literals, you could put them in the ViewData, but if you're following a true MVC model you should create a model for the view with corresponding properties. Considering you're porting from an existing ASP.NET page, setting up a new model for each new view/page may carry a lot ov overhead, in which case stick it in the ViewData.