# How to render a list string that hold html tags as string value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of alot of index that holds html tags like `<input>`, `<select>` and `<td>`. My problem is that when rendering those values, it just prints its normal values not as html tags:

**Img**:
[image: Where a part of that its render]

- Code:

  @foreach(var field in ViewBag.Fields)
      {

  ```
      @field
  }
  ```
- I've tried this as well but both render the same:

  ```
  @foreach(var field in ViewBag.Fields)
  { 

      @Server.HtmlEncode(field);
  }
  ```
- And

  ```
            @foreach(var field in ViewBag.Fields)
          { 

              @Html.Encode(field);
          }
  ```

But here the result:

[image: Still not work]

What should I do to make it work? Any suggestion?

Comment: Try something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249018/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-literal-tag-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @emd - MVC changed quite a bit since 2009.

Comment: Dont know why peope down voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are HTML encoding the values - this is why you are getting them output as encoded HTML (this is also the *safe* default of razor).

Use the [`Raw` helper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to output HTML that is not encoded:

```
@Html.Raw(field);
```