# Literal control in asp net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've been searching for another way to do the same thing the asp.net literal control used to do. For those who don't know it, it allows us to format HTML and store it in a database, for instance, and when we load it is already formatted. Personally, I don't quite like to do this, but I'm working on a project where the company implemented it like this, so unless they agree to change it, I'll have to find a solution for this.

So, is there any way reach the same end as the literal control did?

Comment: See [What is the equivalent of the "literal" tag in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249018/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-literal-tag-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: It didn't seem to work. Maybe because it looks to me like it's not the asp.NET core, but rather the classic asp.NET. Not sure. Maybe it is, since they reference Razor... But anyway, it still doesn't work. But, at this stage it's more like curiosity. They told me that it's probably going to be changed by hand (the texts in the database) or even rewritten.

Comment: OK, syntax should be the same though. Might be worth updating your answer with why this approach does not appear to work,  symptoms etc. Do your literals include scripts?

Comment: No, just html tags such as <br/>